# Identify query run time

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that returns results very fast, seconds. But when I want to fetch all the rows it takes several hours.

If my definition of how long a query takes to run is to fetch all rows, how can one measure this besides actually fetching all the rows?

Would `select count (*)` on all rows be a good indicator on how long it would take to fetch all rows?

Comment: No, it is not. Some database engines will use optimizations to obtain un constrained record counts that mask the IO necessary to scan the table. Additionally, you have to factor in the time to transmit the records across the wire to the client. This is just part of some factors in the time it takes to retrieve all of the data.

Comment: You generally can't predict how long a query is going to take without actually running it. It might be that you can use `v$session_longops` to extrapolate how much work there is still to do, but that only really works where the query consists only of full scans and hash joins in a straightforward plan. Sometimes wrapping it in a `select count(*)` can be a useful diagnostic approach, but only if the execution plan is more or less unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

select count(*) is going to likely do a table scan to return the total number of records.

Depending what is in the table and how it is indexed the count(*) would most likely return faster then running a select *

You could run some baselines on your table by using set statistics time on and set statistics io on.

I would also suggest running with client statistics.

Also, try running a top 100, 1000, 10000 with the above turned on.

When I performance tune I like to look at actual execution plan and estimated execution plan